# Belongs to association works on local but not on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `student` table and a `classrooms` table. I have a line of code in my students index view

```
<td><%= student.classroom.classroom_name %></td>
```

I am trying to display the classroom name associated with the `student.classroom_id`.  This code works on the local development environment using sqlite3 but when I copy the code up to my cPanel webserver using MySQL I get this error

```
undefined method `classroom_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

I have copied all code from the local install to the server.
I have added a foreign key in a migration.
I have run `rails db:migrate` on server.

classroom.rb

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
  validates :classroom_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50}

  has_many :students, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :families, through: :students
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [ :Active, :Deactive ]
  belongs_to :classroom, optional: true

  has_many :student_group_assignments
  has_many :student_groups, through: :student_group_assignments
end
```

Error on cPanel server `undefined method`classroom_name' for nil:NilClass`
but it does work on local ruby on rails install.

Comment: Do you have entries for `student` and `classroom` tables in production? As per the given error, the` student.classroom` object is empty for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error, you are getting on production, clearly, there is no `classroom` entry for that student in the table.
However, if this is the case you should use

```
<td><%= student.classroom.try(:classroom_name) %></td>
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you so much